# How to Include Image tag in JSPF file

Tags: jsp, jsp-fragments

**I want to image to be included in "usermenu.jspf file which is then included in main flat_status.jsp file**

```
        <tr  title="Apply Here">
        <td height="41" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/user_manager.jpg" width="38" height="41"></td>
      <td height="41" class="leftPanel">Apply Here</td>
    </tr>
```

I have used following tag to include JSPF file in Main JSP file

```
 <jsp:include page="WEB-INF/jspf/usermenu.jspf"></jsp:include>
```

I hv tried this one bt it doesnt work...can anyone help me out...???

Here is Screen shot for my files directory

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/4/70285685.jpg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a relative path

```
<img src="../images/user_manager.jpg"
```

since your images folder is one level above your jspf file . Check out [this](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/RelativeLinks) link .

Comment: @SagarDumbre also, please do not forget to accept the correct answer by checking on the tick mark once your are happy with an answer - any answer for that matter .

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `<jsp:include page="...."></jsp:include>` you have to give file extension as .jsp insted of the .jspf

or you can use `<%@ include file="...." %>` instead of the jsp:include ..